# Не могу скомпилировать app! Puppeteer + Electron-builder/packager

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

Написал я скрипт с использованием Puppeteer (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)
Я запускаю через терминал - все работает! Потом стала задача сделать exe файл.
И тут я начал работать с electron-builger & packager.
Сделал так: запускаю electron, высвечивается окно там кнопка 'start script' и после запускается chrome и выполняет скрипт.
**Так вот, главное** что при компиляции через builder нет ошибок кроме

```
no native production dependencies
```

Запускаю нажимаю старт и ничего не происходит!

При использовании packager-a оно делает папку *release-builds* в которой и лежит exe-файл. Запускаю и все работает, так же работает у товарища у которого установлен Node.js ! А перекидываю на комп где не установлен node.js - не работает!

Помогите кто плотно работал с этими модулями!!! Я думаю дело в dependencies(зависимостях). Или быть может в отсутствии node.js на компе заказчика, но при компиляции оно все необходимое должно подтягивать же.
мой package.json

`{
  "name": "my_parser",
  "version": "1.1.2",
  "description": "first app electron",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "package-win": "electron-packager . parser-mydoska --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --icon=build/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"parser mydoska\"",
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "my first parser",
    "productName": "parser_mydoska",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "author": "makas",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^3.0.9",
    "electron-builder": "^20.33.2",
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0"
  }
}`

P.S. Гуглил, пробовал по разному, разбирался, лазил в issues на github  но все тщетно. Сразу говорю что этот json, в нем все сразу, и для builder-a и для packeager-a.

Comment: после установки пакетов или перед сборкой приложения запускай `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild`

Comment: но, имхо, решение упаковывать один движок на хроме в другой движок на хроме выглядит довольно странным. я бы посоветовал просто повторить ту же функциональность средствами электрона

Comment: @nörbörnën, извини, это где мне искать этот файл? У меня есть только electron-build http://prntscr.com/loj7c2 Где он должен быть? и что мне сделать что бы он появился!

Comment: @nörbörnën установил rebuilder, запустил cmd файл перед npm run dist и вот http://prntscr.com/lojkbp